# KeyError: "['place', ...] not in index"

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have the following code

```
df = pd.read_csv("LR7_obolon.txt")
df.head()

f = ['rival', 'place', 'leaders', 'new_players', 'rain']
x = df[f]
y = df['victory']
print(y)
```

My txt file looks like

```
rival, place, leaders, new_players, rain, victory
1,1,1,1,1,1
1,1,1,1,0,1
1,1,0,0,0,1
0,1,0,0,1,1
0,0,0,0,0,0
0,1,0,0,1,1
1,0,1,1,1,0
0,1,1,0,0,-
```

When I run my code I get the following error, in the source code I didn't see any other lines of code, so I don't know what is wrong with that part

```
  KeyError Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\..\LR7.ipynb Cell 3' in <cell line: 3>()
      1 df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
      2 f = ['rival', 'place', 'leaders', 'new_players', 'rain']
----> 3 x = df[f]
      4 y = df['victory']
      5 print(y)

File d:\Programs\Miniconda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:3511, in DataFrame.__getitem__(self, key)
   3509     if is_iterator(key):
   3510         key = list(key)
-> 3511     indexer = self.columns._get_indexer_strict(key, "columns")[1]
   3513 # take() does not accept boolean indexers
   3514 if getattr(indexer, "dtype", None) == bool:

File d:\Programs\Miniconda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:5782, in Index._get_indexer_strict(self, key, axis_name)
   5779 else:
   5780     keyarr, indexer, new_indexer = self._reindex_non_unique(keyarr)
-> 5782 self._raise_if_missing(keyarr, indexer, axis_name)
   5784 keyarr = self.take(indexer)
   5785 if isinstance(key, Index):
   5786     # GH 42790 - Preserve name from an Index

File d:\Programs\Miniconda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:5845, in Index._raise_if_missing(self, key, indexer, axis_name)
   5842     raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
   5844 not_found = list(ensure_index(key)[missing_mask.nonzero()[0]].unique())
-> 5845 raise KeyError(f"{not_found} not in index")

KeyError: "['place', 'leaders', 'new_players', 'rain'] not in index"
```

Im really very bad at python, so please help, how can I fix that? I've read a lot of similar issues but I don't know how to reindex

Comment: This is saying the dataframe doesn't have 'place', 'leaders', 'new_players', 'rain'.  I suspect this is a whitespace issue.   After you read_csv do a `df.to_dict()` to look at your column headers.  The to solve, I would `df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()` after read_csv.  You might have something like ' place', ' leaders', ' new_players', where you had spaces after comma.

Comment: @ScottBoston yeah, u were right, i just mistakenly added spaces before, i fixed that issue and it is working now, thank you ♥

Answer (score 0):

Using the file you provided, I ran this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("LR7_obolon.txt")
print(df.columns)
```

The output was:

```
Index(['rival', ' place', ' leaders', ' new_players', ' rain', ' victory'], dtype='object')
```

Note the spaces in the column names `' place'`, `' leaders'`, `' new_players'`, `' rain'`, and `' victory'`.

You can remove those spaces from the header line in your file, or strip the spaces from the column names after you load the data.

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
```